# Rviz hydro cannot launch node robot_state_publisher

Tags: rviz, roslaunch, robot-state-publisher, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried to complete this tutorial: gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_A_URDF_In_Gazebo

When I'm launching:

> roslaunch rrbot_description
> rrbot_rviz.launch

I got this error:

```
  ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_state_publisher/state_publisher]: robot_state_publisher
    ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
    ROS path [1]=/home/wojciech/catkin_ws/src
    ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
    ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

Rviz launches but there is some worns and errors:

- FIXED FRAME: No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [link1] does not exist
- No transform from [camera_link] to [link1]
- No transform from [link2] to [link1]
- ...

My configuration:

- ROS Hydro
- Ubuntu 13

I will be grateful for your help,

Wojciech

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84071/rviz-hydro-cannot-launch-node-robot_state_publisher/) by [Wojciech](https://answers.ros.org/users/7006/wojciech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install robot_state_publisher:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-09-27**:
I had this same problem.  Why is ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher not installed with ros-hydro-desktop-full?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-27**:
Until now robot_state_publisher was not part of any hydro metapackage. That has been changed recently (https://github.com/ros/metapackages/commit/4df7e45085a5c7e840323f5f871f860961b525a5) and will included in the next sync.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-09-27**:
Thanks @Dirk Thomas.